# Search data in variable table Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-tables

In my Excel file, I have data split up over different tables for different values of parameter X.

I have tables for parameter X for values 0.1, 0.5, 1, 5 and 10. Each table has a parameter Y at the far left that I want to able to search for with a few data cells right of it. Like so:

X = 0.1

| Y | Data_0 | Data_1 | Data_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.071251 | 0.681281 | 0.238509 |
| 2 | 0.283393 | 0.509497 | 0.397196 |
| 3 | 0.678296 | 0.789879 | 0.439004 |
| 4 | 0.788525 | 0.363215 | 0.248953 |

etc.

Now I want to find Data_0, Data_1 and Data_2 for a given X and Y value (in two separate cells).

My thought was naming the tables X0.1 X0.5 etc. and when defining the matrix for the lookup function use some syntax that would change the table it searches in. With three of these functions in adjacent cells, I would obtain the three values desired.
Is that possible, or is there some other method that would give me the result I want?

Thanks in advance

On the question what would be my desired result from this data:
I would like A1 to give the value for the X I'm searching for (so 0.1 in this case)
A2 would be the value of Y (let's pick 3)

then I want C1:E1 to give the values 0.678... 0.789... 0.439...

Now from usmanhaq, I think it should be something like:

```
=vlookup(A2,concatenate("X",A1),2)
=vlookup(A2,concatenate("X",A1),3)
=vlookup(A2,concatenate("X",A1),4)
```

for the three cells.
This exact formulation doesn't work and I can't find the formulation that does work.

Comment: Use string concatenation to build the link to the table and than use indirect() function to refer to that link in your formula.

Comment: What would be your output from provided sample data? And explain logic behind it.

Comment: "I have tables for parameter X for values 0.1, 0.5, 1, 5 and 10." << does this data sits on one table / one sheet / multiple file ? (any screenshot?)

Comment: if it is applicable.. you may explore https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-xlookup-function or https://exceljet.net/formula/index-and-match-with-multiple-criteria